# jquery mobile navigation bar icon size

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using this piece of code for my nav bar

```
<a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a>
```

with the following CSS

```
.ui-icon-home {
       background: url("home.png") no-repeat 50% 50% !important;      
}
```

This code works perfectly and replaces default icon image but I cant use large icons here. I want to use 22 * 22 px icons. When I try to use 22 * 22 px icons jQuery Mobile encaps icons inside a circle and thus showing only some part of my custom icon I want to remove circle.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following css.This will override the default values for icon classes.

```
.ui-icon-home {
   background: url("home.png") no-repeat 50% 50% !important;      
   -moz-border-radius:0px;
   -webkit-border-radius:0px;
   border-radius:0px;
   width:22px;
   height:22px;
   margin-top:-12px;/*Adjust this value to position the icon*/
}
```

Comment: if want to change the size to 32x32 for low resoultion & 80x80 for HD screens. its not working. need your suggestion

Comment: Use a media query like `@media only screen and (min-width: 32em) {`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it with the following code:

```
.ui-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

It removes the black shadow circle behind the icons and makes it 22px height/width.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For icons twice as big as the regular size, use:

```
 .ui-icon-custom::after {
   background-image: url( "custom.svg");
 }
 .big-icon {
   padding-top: 4em;
   height: 6em;
 }
 .big-icon::after {
   margin-left: -1.3em;
   width: 2.6em;
   height: 2.6em;
   background-size: 2.6em 2.6em;
   border-radius: 0;
 }
```

where custom.svg is your custom icon. Remember to add two classes to your button: `big-icon` and `ui-icon-custom`.

Answer (score 0):

The class .ui-icon in the jquery mobile has a border radius of 9 px - This might be what is causing your problems. Try changing your css to:

```
.ui-icon-home {
   background: url("home.png") no-repeat 50% 50% !important;      
   -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
   border-radius:0px
}
```