# JQuery mobile use 36x36 icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How I can use the 36x36 icons instead of 18x18? I can't find anything where it is explained or an example. I just want to use bigger icons!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Jquery Documentation are very clear so far i know, and about the larger icon please have a look at this link. [Jquery Navbar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that but I am not using glyphish icons I am using https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack so they are not single icons they are a pack and I don't know how to make it so it takes the 36 size ones. If I change the link in the .css file it stops finding the icons.

Comment: even i was also doing some R&D and i found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348729/jquery-mobile-navigation-bar-icon-size

Comment: Yes, as all the icons where in the same template I had to adjust the css in order to put the images I wanted in the center. I don't remenber exactaly which parameters I touched...it was long time ago! But it was playing with the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the OP's revisions to the question:

---

The problem was that I am using a [jQuery mobile icon pack](http://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack) and I had to modify the css file in order to adjust the position of each icon.